# How can i set up Angular 2.0 workspace in eclipse kepler

Tags: java, angularjs, node.js, eclipse, typescript

I am Trying to set up workspace in eclipse for Angular 2.0 
I have tried installing NodeJS from http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/
and typescript from http://eclipse-update.palantir.com/eclipse-typescript/

while installing NodeJS from market place i had some problem

am stuck after that :(

can anyone help me out what to do after that ???

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.diniscruz.com/2014/02/using-angularjs-in-eclipse-part-1.html

https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started

This link explains how to install and configure AngularJS Eclipse. This Eclipse plugin is based on the powerful javascript inference engine tern.js which is written in javascript. To use this engine on Java context, tern.java is used. It executes tern.js with node.js. That's why you will see that, you must install node.js server or use an embed node.js.

If you don't install node.js or don't use an embed node.js, only syntax coloring and completions directives will be available in HTML editor.

Comment: the question was about Angular2 and not Angular1. Your answer is for Angular1 and not Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I'm the author of [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started).

I suggest you that you install [Angular2 Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started) (which is not released today):

- it is based on [TypeScript IDE](https://github.com/angelozerr/typescript.java/wiki/Getting-Started) for TypeScript support.
- it integrates [angular-cli](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/AngularCLI).
- it extends WTP HTML Editor to support [Angular2 syntax inside the HTML editor](https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse/wiki/HTML-Editor).

Angular2 Eclipse requires `Eclipse JEE Neon` installation.